# Loop space of $S^1$

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

How concretely can the (based) loop space $\Omega S^1$ of $S^1$ be described? I know it's a space with homotopy groups $\pi_0(\Omega S^1) \simeq \mathbb{Z}$ and $\pi_i(\Omega S^1) \simeq 0$ for $i>0$, so $\Omega S^1$ has countably infinite components, each of which is contractible. What else can one say about it?

Comment: It's homotopy equivalent to $\mathbb{Z}$ (as an H-space, even). What else is there to say?

Comment: Ok. I was trying to get some intuition about loop spaces, and I guess homotopy theorists only care about spaces up to homotopy, so I guess $\mathbb{Z}$ is all one needs to think about in this case.

Comment: If you care about this space up to homeomorphism, the connected component of the identity is homeomorphic to the loop space of $\mathbb{R}$. This is just some infinite-dimensional topological vector space.